# firebase cloud functions - deployment error can't find required modules

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

ERROR BELOW, I've seen a similar/the same question been asked before and have tried all the answer though to no avail, the one  Error: Cannot find module '../key/socialapekey.json' part refers to the private key, I am 99% I have reference this correctly, I'm quite stuck and any help would be appreciated.

[I am 99% I have reference this correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP7nq.png)

```
functions[createScream(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '../key/socialapekey.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/index.js:8:39)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: You can't reference files outside your `functions` folder, as they are not packaged and deployed when you deploy your function. Try putting `socialapekey.json` in the functions directory and see if that helps.

Comment: michael bleigh I tried this ran npm install but now I get; Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'socialapekey.json'
Require stack:
- /Users/benpalmer/Desktop/socialape-functions/functions/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js

Comment: sorry beginner mistake works now that i put ./socialapekey.json was missing the ./ .     thanks for your help